# For Loop Odd and Even Numbers

Tags: c#, algorithm, for-loop

I am creating a report with the following logic/algorithm:

Considering the following:

1. input a counting number n
2. print n
3. if (n==1) then stop
4. else if n is odd then n = 3*n+1
5. else n = n/2
6. go back to step 2

I have a static function:

```
static int nCalc()
{
  int n;
  for(n=1; n<=200; n++)
  {

    if (n == 1)
    {
      fileOut.WriteLine("{0}", n);
    }
    else if (n % 2 == 0)
    {
      n = 3 * n + 1;
    }
    else
    {
      n = n / 2;
    }
    return n;

  }

}
```

I am getting:

```
CS0161 - not all code paths return a value
```

This is where I am lost. Should each else and else if have a return bool value? I may not have the correct algorithm in place as it is.

What I will be basically doing is looping through each number from 1 to 200 using this algorithm. So I should have n out put such as:

```
fileOut.WriteLine(" N  RCL    N  RCL    N  RCL    N  RCL    N  RCL    N  RCL    N  RCL");
fileOut.WriteLine("--- ---   --- ---   --- ---   --- ---   --- ---   --- ---   --- ---");
```

Where under N I will have 1, 2, 3, 4 then under RCL and next to my numbers I will have 1, 2, 8, 3 etc.

Thanks,

Comment: Why even have a for loop if you have a return inside it?

Comment: You need a `return` after your `for` loop.

Comment: You should put your if --- up to --- return n in a function(n int){blah, blah}.  Then in your loop, call the function.

Comment: Duplicate have very detailed explanation what could cause such error for loops and MSDN explains `if` - [CS0161](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/87cz4k9t.aspx). Please ask new question if that information is not enough to find the answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
static int nCalc()
{
  int n;
  for(n=1; n<=200; n++)
  {

    if (n == 1)
    {
      fileOut.WriteLine("{0}", n);
    }
    else if (n % 2 == 0)
    {
      n = 3 * n + 1;
    }
    else
    {
      n = n / 2;
    }


  }
 return n;
}
```

`return` to be outside of loop

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is unclear, but to answer your question:

```
static int nCalc()
{
  for(...)
  {
    ...
    return n;
  }
  // If the code gets here there is no return.
  // The compiler doesn't know the code can't get here hence the error
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Move the `return` statement out of your `for` loop:

```
static int nCalc()
{

    int n;

    for(n = 1; n <= 200; n++)
    {
        if (n == 1)
        {
            fileOut.WriteLine("{0}", n);
        }
        else if (n % 2 == 0)
        {
            n = 3 * n + 1;
        }
        else
        {
            n = n / 2;
        }
    }

    return n;
}
```

As originally written, you were returning out of the `if` block, before the `for` loop finished executing, hence the warning.

Answer (score 0):

I think you meant to do this

```
static void Main() 
{
   for(int n=1;n<=200;n++)
   {
       fileOut.WriteLine("{0}",Calc(n));
   }
}

static int Calc(int n)
{
    int result;

    if (n == 1)
    {
        result = 0;
    }
    else if (n % 2 == 0)
    {
      result = 3 * n + 1;
    }
    else
    {
      result = n / 2;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A method should always have a return statement that would get executed in any condition. In your case, the return statement is within the for loop which would end up not getting executed if the loop conditions are not met.

Moving the return statement out of the loop would solve your problem.

```
static int nCalc()
{  
   int n;  
   for(...)  
   {    
      ...  
   }  
   return n;
}
```